# creating var from from ajax response

Tags: jquery

I need to create a function and create a js var from ajax response Can I do something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "mypage.php",
     data: "name=John&location=Boston",
     success: function(data){
       var newVar = (data);
     }
  });

  return newVar;
}
```

and on mypage.php

```
// db insert
echo mysql_insert_id(); // return ID of the latest insert
```

I'm not sure if using data is appropriate in this case.

Comment: You should most likely be calling a callback function with the data as the argument from the success method but it is not clear what you are trying to do with this example.  How is the PHP related?  The `return newVar` is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mypage.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(data){
        // <- I'm asynchronous !!!
        var newVar = (data);
    }
});

// <- I return before you set me!
return newVar;
```

AJAX request go talk to the server and then call the `success` method some time later. You can garantuee that `success` will not run before the request has finished. This means you can not return any data.

Instead you need to pass in a callback and use asynchronous programming.

What you want to do instead is something like this.

```
function myFunction(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mypage.php",
        data: "name=John&location=Boston",
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}

myFunction(function (data) {
    // do stuff.
});
```

The PHP looks fine.

As an alternative you may prefer to use jQuery's deferred syntax.

```
function myFunction() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mypage.php",
        data: "name=John&location=Boston"
    });
}

$.when(myFunction()).then(function(data) {
     // handle data return
     someOtherFunction(data);
}, function(error) { 
     // handle ajax error.
});
```

Comment: @santa why do you need a variable. Handle the data in the function

Comment: I needed it to pass into another function. I think I got it. var newVar = data; I was trying to get the new var outside of this function.

Answer (score 0):

- Closure does not have visibilty to `newVar`.
- You cannot return from AJAX function as it is done async.

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative to using `when` as suggested by Raynos, you can just set `async` to `false`.